# Not being able to start lightdm

Tags: linux

I'm trying to use `lightdm` service for my workstation but not being able to enable it.
I have removed `gdm.service` using `yum remove gdm` and currently at init 5.

Now if I pass the command

```
systemctl enable lightgdm.service
```

I'm getting an error:

> ```
> Failed to execute operation: File exists.
> ```

And if I run

```
systemctl status lightgdm.service
```

it shows:

> ```
> lightdm.service - Light Display Manager  
> Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)  
> Active: inactive (dead)  
> Docs: man:lightdm(1)
> ```

Upon reboot the system comes as black screen.

Current status of the system:

```
$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep gdm  
gdm.service masked  
$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep display  
display-manager.service masked  
$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep lightdm  
lightdm.service diabled
```

How to enable `lightdm` then?

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable the GDM service before you enable the LightDM service.  With Yum you just uninstalled the GDM package which is not the same as the associated SystemD service.